# Windows CPU max/min %age settings not being adhered to

Tags: cpu, windows-8.1, power-management

Interesting. I have a Windows 8.1 laptop with and an Intel Core(TM) i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.40GHz with 4 cores and 8 virtual processors.

I have various power profiles in Windows: 1. Power Saver, 2. Balanced, 3. High Performance and 4. Samsung Optimized (it's a Samsung laptop).

I noticed that even if I set, in Windows Power Options, the min and max processor states to 1 and 100% respectively for *all* my power profiles:

- if I choose the Power Saver profile, my CPU clock speed drops to 1.18 GHz;
- if I choose the Balanced profile, it ranges from 1.4 to 2.5 GHz;
- if I choose the High Performance profile, it jumps to 2.7 to 3.1 GHz;
- if I choose the Samsung Optimized profile, it stays above 3 GHz at all times;

Utilization of the CPUs was identical - 6% - no matter what mode was selected.

Remember, I have set the minimum and maximum CPU processor states to identical values across all profiles.  In fact, I've set all power settings to the same across all profiles.

Why are the profiles resulting different CPU states?  I've investigated CPU parking (a hidden power setting unhidden by ParkControl, a free program), but this difference persists even when I select the same CPU parking settings across all profiles.

Comment: Why?  Because the Intel your using supports underclocking in order to extend your time while on battery power.  This is perfectly normal.

Comment: @Jon: You might need to check the **System cooling policy** setting in your power plans in case they are different. Also, the effects of the power plans are more complicated than you are making it sound. For instance, Intel Turbo boost is dependent on the power plan.

Comment: @Ramhound: Any way to see/adjust the settings that would control underclocking?

Comment: @James: System cooling is set identically across all profiles. Any way to control Intel Turbo boost settings?  (And yes, I'm off to Google that right now.)

Comment: @Jon: I'm not sure why you would want all the power plans to behave the same. The whole reason for having different ones is so that you can choose one that best fits your requirements. If you are after maximum performance you should choose the **High Performance** plan.

Comment: @James: I didn't say I would want all my profiles the same, only that they were _not_ the same when given the same settings and I didn't know why they differed.  Think of this as an exercise as wanting to understand exactly why and how they differ.  Here's a real world example of why I need to understand where these profiles differ: I had set Samsung Optimized to be my day-to-day use profile.  I now discover that contrary to my settings, it doesn't _ever_ throttle to 1% even in low use conditions.  Essentially I've been overusing my CPU unnecessarily. I now use Power Saver or Balanced instead.

Comment: @Jon - Sure.  Make every plan exactly the same.  Your CPU isn't going to throttle itself unless it has to otherwise it will be at full freq.

Comment: @Ramhound: It is not underclocking, it is a perfectly normal feature of all modern x86 CPUs called frequency scaling. Underclocking means to clock the processor below its rated frequency range.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman - Underclocking frequency scaling there is little difference.  Your right the technical term is frequency scaling in order to both conserve power and reduce heat.  I promise you I know the difference.

Comment: @Ramhound: That's exactly what I am saying is _not_ happening. I've set all values the same, and I'm getting quite different results. Strange.

Comment: Ah, the downvote. I guess the power management mafia doesn't like my questioning of their questionable power management systems!

Comment: @Jon - You have no other power mangement sofware installed?

Comment: @Ramhound: Nothing.